# Facebook poll with anonymous voting capability

Tags: facebook

I want to create a poll in a group. The requirement is that the list of voters who voted for each option should be hidden from everyone, **including me**. Only the number of votes for each option should be shown to everyone.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to say so, but it is not possible.

Anyhow, there is a work around: You can have the poll on some other website and have a post in facebook linking to the poll.

Answer (score -1):

[mylittlepoll](http://www.mylittlepoll.com) allows you to do that.
I just don't see how you can link a poll from there to Facebook.